# Snowflake + Power BI Connections

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to connect Snowflake to Power BI. I have downloaded the ODBC driver
https://sfc-repo.azure.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/win64/latest/index.html but I get an error when I sign in to the snowflake connector with my Microsoft Account. I use AD to login to Snowflake.

[image]

This is the error:

> section Section1;
>
> shared Query1 = let
>       Source = Snowflake.Databases("XXXXXXXXXazure.snowflakecomputing.com",
>   "XXX_XXX_XXXX", [CreateNavigationProperties=null,
>   ConnectionTimeout=null, CommandTimeout=null]) in
>       Source;

Comment: Does your Azure AD login work in the Snowflake Web UI?  I also believe there might be an issue with the March version of Power BI.  Try using the February version instead (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-latest-update-archive) and follow this blog:  https://www.snowflake.com/blog/using-sso-between-power-bi-and-snowflake/

Comment: @Suzy Lockwood. I installed the Feb version and now I get this error: DataSource.Error: The warehouse '' is suspended. You will need to resume it before importing data. Details: DataSourceKind=Snowflake DataSourcePath= .snowflakecomputing.com;DEV OdbcErrors=[Table]

Comment: Sounds like progress!  So, is the warehouse suspended like the message indicates?  You can try resuming it or setting to auto-resume.

Comment: @SuzyLockwood. I am getting close thanks to you. The Snowflake Database is not suspended.

Comment: Do you mean the warehouse is not suspended?  Is there a warehouse name in the error message?  You will want to make sure the warehouse is not suspended (auto-resume or otherwise) and you can also set a default warehouse for the user if it helps.    https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-tasks.html#starting-resuming-a-warehouse
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/warehouses-overview.html#default-warehouse-for-users

Comment: @Suzy Lockwood. I have managed to resolve the issue. I was looking at the incorrect Database now this is working.

Comment: That's great news! Thank you for sharing. I will post my original response as an answer below as well as I believe that helped lead to the resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your Azure AD login work in the Snowflake Web UI? I also believe there might be an issue with the March version of Power BI. Try using the February version instead (learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-latest-update-archive) and follow this blog: snowflake.com/blog/using-sso-between-power-bi-and-snowflake

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same problem. We created a case at Microsoft and they responded there's a faulty DLL file (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\ODBC Drivers\Simba Snowflake ODBC Driver\SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll in PowerBI March 2020 release (2.79.5768.1082) which is causing this failure.

We've received an updated DLL file and now the problem is solved. This update will be included in the next PowerBI release (don't know when this release is planned). For now there are a few possible solutions:

1. Request updated DDL with Microsoft and replace faulty file
2. Go back to the feb 2020 release of Microsoft PowerBI
3. Wait for next release PowerBI

Comment: problem is solved in PowerBI April 2020 release (2.80.5803.1061 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Suzy... In the March release of Power BI Desktop there was a bug introduced which caused this error. Completely install this version and download a previous version. I don't know if the April or May version has been released yet but I would hope MS fixed it in a more recent build.

If you are interested in some information on how to securely implement Power BI scheduled refreshes without using the data gateway, check out the LinkedIn article I wrote within the last day: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/securely-using-power-bi-snowflake-bryan-meier/